# Sorting rows in the attribute table alphabetically in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Clicking the upper slot in the attribute table the column will sort by alphabetically, from the smallest value to largest value

[image]

or from the largest to the smallest

[image]

Is there a way to also sort out the rows names alphabetically?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Right-click* a field and select `Organize columns...`:

[image: Example]

You can then reorder or show specific fields:

[image: Reorder]

Result:

[image: Result]

---

*Note that this is only for display, if you want to reorder the fields permanently, you will need alter the .dbf file which you can do using the **Refactor fields** tool*.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to check if a field in a shapefile with many fields is present and are not interested in the data, you can try this approach:

In the layer properties under *fields* you see all the fields and there you can sort them by clicking on the *name* header. This will not change the order in the attribute table, however!